# Host down alert using prometheus and alertmanager

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have setup a central alertmanager and have installed prometheus, node exporter and configured required rules along with warning / critical thresholds on all the servers which required monitoring and pointed to the alertmanager which will send warning / critical alert on slack.

Now, if one of the machines (which have prometheus + node exporter + rules) is down or not available, the prometheus on it, will not send anything to the alertmanager.

How to solve this problem?

I want to make sure that if any of the prometheus nodes goes (power down / physical down / os crash etc) down, the alertmanager should send the host down alert on slack.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to detect when an host goes down is to use the `up` variable from prometheus. Thanks to this, you can use method like that (in my case, my job is named `prometheus`):

```
up{job="prometheus"}
```

Then config the threshold to "IS BELOW 1" like that:

[image]

In my case, the 192.168.1.62 is well down, not the other.

The "Input B" is values, and "Input A" is variable names.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in this case to run several replicated Prometheus instances, so in case one goes down, the other will still keep evaluating and sending alerts.

AlertManager will take care of deduplicating the same alerts coming from different replicas.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to make a Prometheus server highly available for monitoring and alerting

just run multiple Prometheus server instances with an identical configuration. Both servers then scrape the same metrics, compute the same alerting rules, and forward exactly the same alerts to the Alertmanager.

The Alertmanager can then deduplicate alerts based on their label sets and only send you a single notification.

because if your virtual machine was down, another Prometheus knows the Prometheus service is not working and seems down